# How can i use packagist file to my controller?

Tags: packagist

I have added one packagist now how can i use that to my controller?

I have used my composer command but i added to vendor folder now how to access that file?

composer require jainam/basic-functions

I want to use my functions of that file to my controller

Comment: Please provide more information. Are you using some kind of framework, or just plain PHP?

Comment: I am using laravel @EliasSoares

Answer (score 0):

Reading your package I see some issues there:

1. On composer.json you define a [PSR-4 autoload](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) for `jainam\\basicFunctions` with root on `src` this is almost right, except that the namespace isn't PSR-4 compliant. To fix it, use UpperCamelCase instead of lowerCamelCase. ([Camel Case wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case)
2. Your `basicFunctions.php` also must be in UpperCamelCase.
3. Your `basicFunctions.php` should use the namespace that you defined on `composer.json`.
4. Your `basicFuncions` class is actually a Controller, so call in correctly: `LoginController` or anything that means something.

Fixed that, now you can use the controller you defined in two ways:

## Directly declaring a route for it

If that controller on your package is complete and do not need any extra methods, you can just declare some routes using your controller on your `routes\web.php` file, for example:

```
Route::post('login', ['uses'=>'\Jainam\BasicFunctions\LoginController@login'])
```

## Extending your controller

If you need to add methods or customize methods to your controller, you can extend it inside your Laravel project, creating your own version of LoginController:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers

use Jainam\BasicFunctions\LoginController as BaseLoginController // Must import that class with an alias if using same name on your class

class LoginController extends BaseLoginController {
    // Extend wanted methods here, or add new ones.
}
```

And on your `routes\web.php` file you just need to remove that namespace:

```
Route::post('login', ['uses'=>'LoginController@login'])
```

Hope this can help you, I'm writing from mobile.

Also, check for [PhpDoc comments pattern](https://docs.phpdoc.org/references/phpdoc/basic-syntax.html), and consider using it.

Comment: {message: "Class 'Jainam\BasicFunction\BasicFunctions' not found",…}
exception: "Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError"
file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\data-entry-form\app\Http\Controllers\jobController.php"
line: 87
message: "Class 'Jainam\BasicFunction\BasicFunctions' not found"
trace: [{function: "getCities", class: "App\Http\Controllers\jobController", type: "->"}, {,…}, {,…},…]
It is still showing error message i have tried using use \Jainam\BasicFunction\BasicFunctions; and called method BasicFunctions::checkEmailExists();